# Sequelize MariaDB - Insert emoji character

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, mariadb, utf

I'm developing a telegram bot. Everything is ok, except the unicode character (emoji). I mean, when I do insert things into the table, it always show the **question mark** if there any emoji. (i think the table doesn't recognize the character).
[image]

I did some changes on database and tables, and i converted some of the configuration to utf8mb4, here's the [reference link](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4)

Here's the table setup

[image]

I did the **repair** and **optimize** table.

Here's my sequelize model

[image]

I need this, because when i retrieve the data from the database, it will show the emoji when i pass it to the room chat (not the **question marks thing**)

Thanks guys!
Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT**

I added 2 lines on the options on sequelize.js, and still nothing happen

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you connect to db, add the `charset` option.

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql', //maybe modify this to mariadb
    dialectOptions: {
      charset: 'utf8mb4'
    },
});
```

Comment: where to modify it dude?

Comment: @Webster I just edited my answer. You should find where you get the db connection and modify it.

Comment: @solarshell, see my edited post above, i added those line, still not working

Comment: You likely need to set the `charset` in the table definition as well as the connection.

Answer (score 2):

you can also add charset on table definition to enable emoji character support in that table, while defining the table add char set like this

`sequelize.define('roomDetails',{firstName: sequelize.STRING},{charset: 'utf8mb4'})`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to put the following on the first line of my User model:

```
// make sure db/client/connection can support emoji
sequelize.query("SET NAMES utf8mb4;");
// confirm settings
sequelize.query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'").then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```